# C. How to read word by word in specific lines from a file

Tags: c, string, file, getline

I was wondering if it's possible to read from a 3M lined file word by word, and save the words of lines 1-1M in array1 (lines 1M-2M to array2, etc) to 3 arrays of strings. The problem is when reading word by word you cannot count the lines.

Obviously, one could try to read line by line and tokenize the words from the line, but it seems to be too much work. Is there a better way?

Comment: Possibly, we need some more details. But, assuming you are using `fscanf` to read the words, then you *can* count the lines. Code like `char word[20], sep; fscanf(fp, "%20s%c", word, &sep);` will read the (space-delimited) word and *then* the separator. Check that separator for a newline and, if it is, increment the line count.

Comment: Is it possible that some words in the file are [hyphenated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syllabification), so that one word starts in one line and ends in the next line? In that case, if the word starts in line 1000000 and ends in line 1000001, should the word go into `array1` or into `array2`?

Comment: about the hyphenated words: no, there's no such case. Also, each line is exactly 100 letters long and no punctuation marks.

Comment: @DosUzumaki: Does this mean that the words are all separated either by a single space character or by a single newline character, and never by anything else?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel that's exactly right.

Comment: @AdrianMole: One issue with your solution is that it will not count empty lines. However, meanwhile, OP has stated in a later comment that all lines are exactly 100 letters long, so this should not be an issue.

Comment: @DosUzumaki: When you say that every line is exactly "100 letters" long, do you mean 100 characters long including all space characters and including the newline character? Or do you mean 100 alphabetical letters, so not counting the space characters and the newline character?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel it's 100 characters including the space but not the newline. Lemme give you the example of 1 line: 
`sbf7jnUBTiVPL24fCZrmeytICYpWHp4Z41 vDMDYeNu qbFjbZnFjmIoXF23oo1hHfPOMjvFeR2tBucHRMHGGcbWy7PlnxpjzJZT`

I know the words are weird, but this is what's in the file.

Comment: "but it seems to be too much work" It isn't.

Comment: I believe it would be best to read the text file one line at a time using [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets). You can divide the individual line into words using [`strtok`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok).

Comment: Alternatively, you could map the file into memory with `mmap` and then tokenize it with `strtok`.

Comment: @AdrianMole `char word[20], sep; fscanf(fp, "%20s%c", word, &sep);` is **bad** code as the width is 1 too great and it fails to count consecutive `'\n'` and does not check `fscanf()` return value.  Sadly OP has posted too little info.